# Get differten items of the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I have make a script. That set li items on different positions on the page. This positions are fixed positions. The positions are set in the array.

But this li items. Must have a rotate. I make a rotate with css3 transform. Every li item must have a fixed rotate. I put 8 fixed rotate positions in a array. But i have a problem. Every li item get the same rotate position. How can i fix. That every li item get a other fixed position of the array.

You can see the code here: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5L9FN/7/)

Or here is my code:

```
var images = [];

// Constructor for the "Position" structure
function Position(left, top) {
    this.left=left;
    this.top=top;
}

function rotate(object, degrees) {
    object.css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',
     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
       '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
          'transform' : 'rotate('+degrees+'deg)',  
               'zoom' : 1
    });
}

// sortFunction routine to help randomize array
function rand(ar){
    return 0.5-Math.random();
}

// Array containing the 8 positions you want to use
var positionArray = [
      new Position(0,  0) 
    , new Position(50, 50) 
    , new Position(100,100) 
    , new Position(150,150) 
    , new Position(200,200) 
    , new Position(250,250) 
    , new Position(300,300) 
    , new Position(350,350) 
];

var rotateArray = [0, 15, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];

function init() {
    $('.friend-selection li > div').each(function(){

        var id = this.id;
        var img = $('#img_' + id);
        var imageIndex = parseInt(id.substring(id.length - 1))-1; // This is a hack because you're using "picture*" as the id

        $("#parent_" + id).css({ //apply the position to parent divs
            top     : positionArray[imageIndex].top,
            left    : positionArray[imageIndex].left
        });

        rotate($(".friend-selection li"), rotateArray[imageIndex]);
    });
};

positionArray.sort(rand);

init();
```

Comment: I honestly suggest you to learn some JS basics and try to understand the code you get as answers. Building together your application by asking questions here won't bring you far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
rotate($("#parent_" + id), rotateArray[imageIndex]);
```

Instead of:

```
rotate($(".friend-selection li"), rotateArray[imageIndex]);
```